# Checkbox state on double click in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

My goal is to limit amount of selected checkboxes on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var globalCounter = 0;
var maxCount = 2;
function updateCounter(obj) {
    globalCounter += (obj.checked ? 1 : -1);
    console.log(globalCounter);
    if (globalCounter > maxCount && obj.checked) {
        obj.checked = false;
        globalCounter = maxCount;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type=checkbox onclick="updateCounter(this);">
<input type=checkbox onclick="updateCounter(this);">
<input type=checkbox onclick="updateCounter(this);">
<input type=checkbox onclick="updateCounter(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

Everything seems fine until I try double click on checkboxes in IE 11. 2 `onclick` events triggered and in the second event I have incorrect `obj.checked`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: could try adding a listener for double click and preventing default

Comment: otherwise try `... onclick="return updateCounter(this);"`

Comment: @chrlietfl I tried to add ondblclick="return event.preventDefault();" for every checkbox, but it didn't help.

Comment: Adding `return` didn't help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may recommend a better way of doing this . . .

```js
function updateCounter(obj) {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check1');
  var checked = [];

  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checked[checked.length] = checkboxes[i];
    }
  }

  if (checked.length > 2) {
    obj.checked = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type=checkbox name="check1" onclick="updateCounter(this);">
  <input type=checkbox name="check1" onclick="updateCounter(this);">
  <input type=checkbox name="check1" onclick="updateCounter(this);">
  <input type=checkbox name="check1" onclick="updateCounter(this);">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But why don't use just counter instead of `checked` array?

Comment: @red1ynx, the reason yours didn't work was because you had a global counter.  That leaves room for plenty of errors (like double click).  This array is populated with the number of checkboxes that are selected **every time you click a checkbox.**

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- Don't use inline event handlers.
- Don't listen to `click` event. Checkboxes can change in other ways, e.g. keyboard. And IE sometimes doesn't trigger a `click` event when you doubleclick.
- There is no need to return booleans.

Assuming you won't create additional checkboxes dynamically,

```js
var globalCounter = 0,
    maxCount = 2,
    els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
  els[i].addEventListener('change', handler);

function handler(e) {
  globalCounter += this.checked ? 1 : -1;
  if (globalCounter > maxCount) {
    this.checked = false;
    globalCounter = maxCount;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```